# why the calculation changes the integer format to another format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I made a code that adds a value to each line in the field and then transforms it into the required format
Next to each added number, assigns its original number to the entry

The problem is that the second iteration of the number does not print integers but in a different format. I try to format it as in the first iteration.
In subsequent iterations, the problem is the same
I don't understand why he does that
Can you help me how to solve it?

My output

```
  # first iteration
[[-111.    1.]
 [-112.    2.]
 [-113.    3.]
 [-221.    1.]
 [-222.    2.]
 [-223.    3.]
 [-331.    1.]
 [-332.    2.]
 [-333.    3.]
 [-441.    1.]
 [-442.    2.]
 [-443.    3.]
 [-551.    1.]
 [-552.    2.]
 [-553.    3.]] 
  #second iteration
[[-6.610e+02  1.000e+00] 
 [-6.620e+02  2.000e+00]
 [-6.630e+02  3.000e+00]
 [-7.710e+02  1.000e+00]
 [-7.720e+02  2.000e+00]
 [-7.730e+02  3.000e+00]
 [-8.810e+02  1.000e+00]
 [-8.820e+02  2.000e+00]
 [-8.830e+02  3.000e+00]
 [-9.910e+02  1.000e+00]
 [-9.920e+02  2.000e+00]
 [-9.930e+02  3.000e+00]
 [-1.101e+03  1.000e+00]
 [-1.102e+03  2.000e+00]
 [-1.103e+03  3.000e+00]]
```

I need

```
[[-111.    1.]
 [-112.    2.]
 [-113.    3.]
 [-221.    1.]
 [-222.    2.]
 [-223.    3.]
 [-331.    1.]
 [-332.    2.]
 [-333.    3.]
 [-441.    1.]
 [-442.    2.]
 [-443.    3.]
 [-551.    1.]
 [-552.    2.]
 [-553.    3.]] 
  #second iteration
[[-661  1] 
 [-662  2]
 [-663  3]
 [-771  1]
 [-772  2]
 [-773  3]
 [-881  1]
 [-882  2]
 [-883  3]
 [-991  1]
 [-992  2]
 [-993  3]
 [-1101 1]
 [-1102 2]
 [-1.103 3]]
```

Full code with comments

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import re

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
p=1
#sys.stdout = open("results.txt", "w")      
with open('emotion_file.txt', mode='w',newline='\n') as emotion_file:
      #remove unnecessary characters-preprocessing
    for i in list(lines):
         if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
            d = str(' '.join(i.split()))
            print(d)
            emotion_file.write(d+'\n')
            
         else:
    
            w = i.replace("=",'')
            w = w.replace(">",'')
            w = w.replace("<",'')
            #print(w)
            w = ', '.join(w.split())
            #y = i[2]
            #y=int(y)+1
              #insert demofile to array
            c=np.array([w])
            
            c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
             
            c1=np.array(c1)
              #save the first number to variable
            frst=c1[0]
            #print(i[0])
               #remove first numbers from array 
            c1=np.delete(c1, 0)       
            n=len(c1)
            sest2=c1 
              #multiplying the field by the first number  
            c1=np.array([c1]*frst)
              #transpose array
            c1=np.transpose(c1)
            #addition value 110
            left1 = np.array([[(p + j) * + 110 for j in range(frst)]] * n) +c1
            left2 = np.array([[(p + j) * -110 for j in range(frst)]] * n) +c1
            
              #if it is a positive number it adds value if it is negative it subtracts
            left=np.where(c1 > 0,left1 , left2)
            #print(left)
    
    
            left=left*-1
            b=np.all(left < 0)     
                    #6.vzorec  
              #edit the field to the correct format          
            sest1=left
            sest = np.zeros((sest1.flatten().shape[0],2))
            sest[:,[0]] = sest1.T.flatten()[:,None]
            sest[:,[1]] = np.tile(sest2,frst)[:,None]
            print(sest,'\n')
                    
            p +=frst
```

demofile.txt:

```
>=5 1 2 3
>=5 1 2 3
```

Comment: Do you need to change output(`-6.610e+02`) to `-661`or `-6.61`?

Comment: 661, but I've already solved it . I used ndarray.astype()

Comment: The first iteration shows float dtype values (see the decimal point).  When the floats in an array differ enough, it displays them with scientific notation, to better handle the precision of the smallest and largest.  I think you want to specify `int` dtype through out. e.g. `np.array(...., int)` and `np.zeros(..., int)`.